# Add a button in active <li>

Tags: jquery, html, list

*Here is my structure :*

```
<ul class="subcategories" id="items-23">
    <li>
        <a data-item="35" class="itemLink">
            others
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-item="24" class="itemLink">
            Cars
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-item="28" class="item-link activeSelection">
            Bikes
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add this button to the activeSelection only :
`<a class="btn item-next" id="NextButton" href="#">Next</a>`. When i click on `<li>` it add activeSelection class.

I tried in the source code. As `<li>` are generated automatically, if i had the button, when see it on every `<li>`.

Someone understand my problem and could have a solution for it ?

Thanks in advance !!!

------------the result expected  -----------

As you see i've selected the first categorie, and my button is displayed

http://rentaweb.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/screenshot.png

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, but if I'm correct, you want a "Next" button that's only visible under the <li> most recently clicked?

Answer (score 1):

To add something to that element with a specific class:

```
$('<input type="button" value="Hello"/>').appendTo('.activeSelection');
```

To register the click event:

```
$('.subcategories').on('click', '.itemLink', function(){
    $('.activeSelection').removeClass('activeSelection'); // Remove the current as suggested
    $(this).addClass('activeSelection');
});
```

Note the usage of the on(), where I filter out the `.itemLink`. This is so it dynamically can handle new elements, w/o the need to re-apply the event-hook.

Comment: Remember to remove the previous `active` class, or else you'll end up with multiples.

Comment: Right, totally forgot, fixed

Comment: Also, it should be `$(this).addClass`, or `this.className = `